# XML support in browsers not only IE9

Tags: xml, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, opera

What is wrong with my code?

```
 <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Лабораторная работа 2</TITLE></HEAD>
        <BODY>
            <XML ID="dsoStudent" SRC="file_1.xml"></XML>
            <H2> Список студентов </H2>
            <TABLE DATASRC="#dsoStudent" BORDER="6" CELLPADDING="5" width="100%"> 
                <THEAD style =”background-color: maroon”>
                <TH> Фамилия</TH>
                <TH> Имя</TH> 
                <TH> Год рождения</TH>
                <TH> Группа</TH> 
                </THEAD>
                <TR ALIGN="center">
                    <TD><SPAN DATAFLD="FAMILY" STYLE="font-style:italic"> </SPAN> </TD>
                    <TD><SPAN DATAFLD="NAME" > </SPAN> </TD>
                    <TD><SPAN DATAFLD="YEAR"> </SPAN> </TD> 
                    <TD><SPAN DATAFLD="GROUP"> </SPAN> </TD>    
                </TR>
            </TABLE></BODY></HTML>
```

[XML CODE in file_1.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwJRM.png)

It works only in IE9. What need fix to make in work on IE9+ and other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using [a non-standard Internet Explorer extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533709%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to display your data. `datasrc` is not a part of any standards, and even Microsoft is moving away from their old non-standard features, which is probably why it does not even work in newer versions of IE.

I would recommend you look into implementing your functionality using current web standards, such as fetching your XML using [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) and using JavaScript to create the elements to display the data. Or perhaps forming the HTML from the data using server-side code.